# Creating Tables and Names with Error code 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I've been struggling to figure out what is producing the error code 1004 in the code below.  I've tried changing the range to ensure that the code selects the correct worksheets and range with little success.

I've also tried commenting **the line of code that I know is producing the erro**r `(Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).Select)`.

When I do comment that line of code, the code executes without an error and goes into the For loop for the correct number or times, but it fails to create all 9 tables as I expect it to.  It will just produce the first table and I verified this using the Name Manger tab under formulas it just creates the first table.

```
    With Worksheets("AEC Assignments")
        For i = 1 To lastc
            With .Columns(i)
            lastr = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                With Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i))
                Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).Select
                Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
                End With
            End With
        Next i

    End With
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'd love to understand why it's happening.  FYI, I'm a total novice and just have a basic understanding of coding, enough to put all of this together and enjoy the challenge of coding.

Thanks and the best to you all!

```
     'Copy Filtered Data
    Dim lrow3 As Long
        lrow3 = Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet10.Range(Sheet10.Cells(1, 7), Sheet10.Cells(lrow3, 7)).Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Paste Filtered Data in New Sheet
    Dim erow4 As Long
    erow4 = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count - 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet11.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("AEC Assignments").Range(Sheet11.Cells(erow4, 1), Sheet11.Cells(erow4, 1))
    Sheets("Teacher Match").Select
    Sheet10.Range("A1:G1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim lastr As Long
    Dim lastc As Long
    lastc = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With Worksheets("AEC Assignments")
        For i = 1 To lastc
            With .Columns(i)
            lastr = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
                With Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i))
                Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).Select
                Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
                End With
            End With
        Next i

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

---

---

Latest update: Code error 1004 is no longer!  Unfortunately, the desired results have yet to be accomplished.  Here is the updated piece of code:

```
`Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("AEC Assignments")

Dim lastr As Long
Dim lastc As Long
wsSrc.Activate
lastc = wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To lastc
        lastr = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).CreateNames Top:=True
    Next i`
```

My purpose for this code was to produce several named cell ranges.  Currently, I'm only getting 1 successfully named range of the 9 it's supposed to produce.

Comment: Snipped out a bit of the code which looks inconsistent in the range treatment.
Maybe define a ws variable

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("AEC Assignments")

and use it in the lastr and lastc definitions and the with statement.

    lastc = wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

I managed to get it to go through without error doing that.

    With wsSrc
    lastr = wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Can you explain the inconsistency to me?  I'd like to understand what you're seeing so I can learn to spot these issues.  I also attempted the suggestion and received the same error.

Comment: I just tried integrating both solutions and it seemed to have fixed the error, but it's not fully resolved my issue!! I removed the with statements and also redefined the variable wsSrc as you recommended.  Getting away from that error is def progress in my book.  I want to celebrate for just a moment :D Yayy!!!  Anyway, I went into the _Name Manger_ to see if I had 9 newly named ranges and I didn't; only have the first one :(  Any ideas??

Comment: Your code would definitely benefit by being written consistently.  It currently has references to `Sheet11` interspersed with `Worksheets("AEC Assignments")`, which must be the same thing, and references to `Sheet10` interspersed with `Worksheets("Teacher Match")`, which I suspect are the same thing.  And then there are references to `Range` and `Cells` which, because they don't have a sheet qualifier, refer by default to the ActiveSheet, and you even use ActiveSheet explicitly in at least one place.

Comment: Also, lastc is calculated as the number of columns on Sheet10, but then you are looping through the columns on Worksheets("AEC Assignments") using lastc as the number of columns to process.  Do the two sheets have equivalent columns?

Comment: Ah! I do now understand what you mean by the consistency of referencing the worksheets.  I will go ahead and make adjustments to ensure that the code is written more consistently throughout.  I'm sure I do this in more than one place.

Comment: Good observation YowE3K.  I just checked and unfortunately, Sheet10 and Sheet11 do no have the same number of columns.  When I added the watch, for lastc, I noticed that the counter was accurate (9).  For some reason although I'm not getting the Error code anymore, I'm still not finding 9 newly formed ranges in my Name Manger.

Comment: (a) What code are you currently using?  The code posted by dbmitch, with `Cells` replaced by `.Cells`?  (b) Do each of your columns on the "AEC Assignments" sheet have the same number of rows?  (If they do, I can give you a single statement to avoid looping through columns.)

Comment: The entire section creating the range names can **probably** be replaced with `Worksheets("AEC Assignments").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.CreateNames Top:=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Withs can sometimes cause problems and in your case you're not even using the `With` in the problem block. Another issue might be that you're trying to Select a Range when it's not clear if that worksheet is active.

You're not even using `With .Columns(i)` so I would eliminate that With block - unless that points to an error in missing logic

If ActiveSheet is not "AEC Assignments" then you need to activate it

**Replace this block of code**

```
With Worksheets("AEC Assignments")
    For i = 1 To lastc
        With .Columns(i)
        lastr = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            With Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i))
            Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).Select
            Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
            End With
        End With
    Next i

End With
```

**With this block**

```
Dim AEC_AssignSht       As Worksheet

Set AEC_AssignSht = Sheets("AEC Assignments")

With AEC_AssignSht
    For i = 1 To lastc
        lastr = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
       .Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).CreateNames Top:=True
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Why do you need to `.Activate` ? you are not using `ActiveSheet`' it works fine also without it since you are using `With Worksheets("AEC Assignments")`

Comment: Definitely.  I understand now regarding the `.Activate` Still working on understanding everything and appreciate all the help I can get.  I tried the replacement and it still gave me the same error code :(

Comment: `.Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(lastr, i)).CreateNames Top:=True` should be `.Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(lastr, i)).CreateNames Top:=True` because the sheet referred to by `Cells` is the ActiveSheet, which is not necessarily "AEC_Assignments".

Comment: Also `lastr = Sheet11.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row` should **probably** be `lastr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row`, but that depends on whether `Sheet11` is the same as `Sheets("AEC Assignments")` or not.  (If it is, the current line is fine.  If it isn't, the OP needs to determine whether he/she really is trying to find the last row on Sheet11 and then use that to perform a task on Sheets("AEC Assignments") - it sounds suspicious to me.)

Comment: (Actually, Sheet11 and Worksheets("AEC Assignments") must be the same thing, because the OP uses `Worksheets("AEC Assignments").Range(Sheet11.Cells(erow4, 1), Sheet11.Cells(erow4, 1))` elsewhere in the code and didn't complain of an error in that line.)

Comment: I am guessing here, it might be that the values in the top row (the names to be used for the range) might be invalid, i.e. a number or other reserved value.
Try renaming the top row to something like 'one', 'two', 'three' etc. for testing and see if the named ranges appear. I suspect they might.